Windows - file input redirection
I am using a Windows program that uses an odd/outdated form of logging : logs of size up to m Bytes are written to up to n plain text files into a logging directory:
logdir\Log001.log  n Bytes
logdir\Log002.log  n Bytes
...
logdir\Log00n.log

then 'rolled over' where Log001.log is erased and Log00(n+1).log is created, etc.
Typically this program runs for long periods of time, can create many GB of logging, and files are often overwritten. This does not help in catching events that may need to be investigated in the future.
In Windows is it possible  to create a 'named' stream logdir\Log001.log?
acting as a sink so the stream can be redirected to for storage/continuous monitoring.
I was thinking of something like a unix 'named pipe' but that seems to mean something different in Windows.
Tee might be useful if it can be used on an existing file opened by another process, but the file names are often changing.
Alternative ideas appreciated.
